# Calling controller method and display return value

Tags: jquery, controller, label

I am using JQuery and calling controller method to display some text in label.

Here is my code-

**Controller method**

```
public string GetText(int number)
{
     string txt = number.ToString();
     return txt;
}
```

**On cshtml page**

```
 @Html.Label(((MyController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetText(1234))
```

But here, the text is not displaying inside the label.
Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: This looks similar to what you are trying to achieve here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302285/how-to-display-dynamic-text-to-html-lable-from-controller

Comment: @danish But here I want to send a parameter with the function. How can I achieve this

Comment: @Aparna : Version of ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @Aparna : If it's possible, can you please share your exact method  implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had noticed that "GetText" not hitting the break point with your code for first time run.

Added the below code run it, then revert the changes to your code then working fine for me.

```
@{
    var valueText =((MyController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetText(1234);
}

@Html.Label(valueText)
@Html.Label(((MyController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetText(1234))
```

---

1. If "GetText" method has some simple logic, without any DB call, the we can use Custom HTML Helpers methods,
   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3194c4/custom-html-helpers-in-mvc/
2. If it is possible to get "number" value during main controller action itself, then use ViewBag / TempData or Create One more property,

   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-in-mvc1

   Call this code in main controller,

   ViewBag.Number = GetText(vm.Property2); OR vm.Property2 = GetText(vm.Property2);
      @Html.Label(ViewBag.Number OR  Model.Property2)
3. @Html.Action / @Html.RenderAction & Partial View. Please find the below link,

   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-action-and-html-renderaction-in-Asp-Net-mvc/
4. It's also possible by jQuery AJAX also.

Please let me know in case of any issues or concerns.

Comment: The requirement is pretty simple. Is there any way I can modify my current code? Whats wrong there? GetText() function returns value but do not display it.

Comment: @Aparna :  I had noticed that "GetText" not hitting the break point with your code for first time run...